# Bootstrap CDN not working with angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a small app in angular and am trying to include the Bootstrap CDN into the head section.  My current head section looks like this:

```
<head>
  <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.0rc3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="todo.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="todo.css">
  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
</head>
```

When I go to refresh the page none of the bootstrap changed have been made.  Is this something going on with Angular or am I just making a dumb mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the wrong URL. You can plug it into your browser to see where it takes you.

yours:

```
http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css
```

correct one:

```
http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

To make sure you have the correct one, always get it from here: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

For me, Instead of using CDN, Adding and referencing the bootstrap css file locally in *dist* folder(or whatever folder you have generated via Angular fixed the issue.